max_of_three using first_result, second_result,
I am an absolute beginner at this and trying Coderslang in Visual Studio.
How do i get the highest number from ..._result? It allways just gives me the first one.
first_result = max_of_three(1, -1, 3)
print(first_result)
second_result = max_of_three(1, 4, 2)
print(second_result)
third_result = max_of_three(1, 2, 2)
print(third_result)

I tried:
def max_of_three(x, y, z):
    max = x
    if y > max:
        max = y
    if z > max:
        max = z
        return max

first_result = max_of_three(1, -1, 3)
print(first_result)
second_result = max_of_three(1, 4, 2)
print(second_result)
third_result = max_of_three(1, 2, 2)
print(third_result)

Result:
3

None

None


As well as the answer below correcting your code, you should also be aware than Python has a built-in function max() which does exactly this for any number of passed values. Such functions are fast because they are in compiled, lower-level code. Using such functions and the many available library modules (such as Numpy for numerical arrays, linear algebra etc) covers most general requirements and adds much 'leverage' to your own coding.

return max should be at the proper nesting level:
def max_of_three(x, y, z):
    max = x
    if y > max:
        max = y
    if z > max:
        max = z
    return max

You clearly want return to be executed always, not only in just one if condition.
If return is not executed, the function returns None.
